# Getting duplicate users in leaderboard

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a leaderboard for the most liked users by counting the likes of their post and ordering them.

However if the user has 2 or more post, it will duplicate the user in the leaderboard with the total likes that he has. Is there a way to fix this? Thank you.

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1500, verbose_name='Content')
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

views.py:

```
def top_user(request):
    top_user = Post.objects.annotate(total_likes=Count('user__post__likes')).order_by('-total_likes')
    context = {'users': top_user}
    return render(request, 'blog/top_user.html', context)
```

html:

```
{% for top in users %}
   <h5>{{ top.user }}</h5> 
   <p>Upvotes: {{ top.total_likes }}</p>     
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query the wrong way, the `top_users` you here present are `Post`s, so that means that *per* posts, you count the number of total likes of that author. But if an author has many posts, they appear multiple times.

You thus should annotate the users:

```
top_user = User.objects.annotate(total_likes=Count('post__likes')).order_by('-total_likes')
```

and thus render it with:

```
{% for user in users %}
   <h5>{{ user }}</h5>
   <p>Upvotes: {{ user.total_likes }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir Willem! Didn't thought about the user itself..